# How to press "OK" for location popup on iOS Appium

Tags: python, ios, mobile, automation, appium

I am trying to automate my mobile web app.Every time it loads, it will ask "___ would like to use your location". User can either hit "don't allow" or "OK."

I am using `self.driver.switch_to.alert.accept()`, but it is accepting the default, which is "don't allow." How can I accept the "OK" instead of "don't allow"?

Comment: Does the "OK" button have a content-desc or a resource-id? Is the alert part of the app? Can you see its identifiers using a device monitor?

Comment: It is an alert that is part of iOS devices. For example, when you use Google Maps, Waze, and Apple Maps on an iOS device, it will open an alert that asked if it could use your location.

Answer (score 1):

That method currently doesn't work for me either.

Did you try to locate "OK" button with Appium Inspector maybe?
I have the same pop up for location, and for me either of these work (xpath or accessibility ID) on iOS.

Something like:

```
allow_access_to_location_ios = (MobileBy.ACCESSIBILITY_ID, 'OK')
```

or

```
allow_access_to_location_ios = (MobileBy.XPATH, '//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name="OK"]')
```

then you call method:

```
self.wait_for_and_accept_alert(*self.allow_access_to_location_ios)
```

and method will wait for the element 15 seconds and click on it if it finds it otherwise it will print an error message:

```
def wait_for_and_accept_alert(self, *locator):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(lambda s: self.driver.find_element(*locator))
        self.driver.find_element(*locator).click()
    except TimeoutException:
        print('Unable to find element')
```

Answer (score 0):

1. For Accepting system alert create a method:

   ```
   def accept_notification_alert(self):
   print('Accept alert')
   try:
       self.driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
   except WebDriverException:
       print('Webdriver error: %s' % WebDriverException.msg)
   ```
2. For dismissing system alert you can create method:

   ```
   def dismiss_notification_alert(self):
   print('Dismiss alert')
   try:
       self.driver.switch_to.alert.dismiss()
   except WebDriverException:
       print('Webdriver error: %s' % WebDriverException.msg)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If a default approach (`switch_to.alert.accept()`) desn't work, you may try [mobile gestures](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/ios/ios-xctest-mobile-gestures/):

```
driver.execute_script('mobile: alert', {'action': 'accept', 'buttonLabel': <your button label here>});
```

Answer (score -1):

I understood that you are asking for the device location alert. You can identify and use the Xpath of OK button to click. I have used the following code (in java) for an alert appears in the app.

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[7]/UIAAlert[1]/UIACollectionView[1]/UIACollectionCell[1]/UIAButton[1]")).click();

Comment: This example is referencing to iOS UIAutomation based on locator and would not be helpful these days: it was deprecated at iOS version 9.3.x. Now with Appium using XCUITest the proper way to interact with system popup http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/ios/ios-xctest-mobile-gestures/